# Fourier transform of $\operatorname{sech}^2(x)$

Tags: fourier-series, hyperbolic-functions

I'm trying to derive the Fourier transform of various hyperbolic functions and I don't see how to derive the transform of $\operatorname{sech}^2(x)$. I got as far as decomposing the function into exponentials but that's it.

$$\operatorname{sech}^2(x) = \dfrac{4}{\left(\mathrm{e}^x+\mathrm{e}^{-x}\right)^2} $$

Comment: Since sech is (up to silly constants) [an eigenfunction of Fourier transform](/q/799616), just take convolution square.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: See [this answer](/a/1436615).